# Boolean function does not work properly

Tags: c++, arrays, function, char, boolean

I have trouble to come up with a Boolean function as expected by the assignment. I just need some explanations as I want to write my own code. I am supposed to write a MIPS code that actually counts the number of Uppercase, Lowercase, Vowels, Consonants and Digits in a string. I am writing the code in C++, then I will translate into MIPS assembly. I pasted the requirement below followed by the way the function bool consonant(char c) should look like (idea given by my professor). The problem is that it seems I am missing some information to make that function work. Can anyone provide me more information regarding that function? I don't need a code, just the missing details. Your help will be very appreciated.

//requirement of assignment bellow

To determine if an ASCII character c is a vowel or a consonant, write two functions bool vowel(char c) and
bool consonant(char c). Use the stack to pass the character argument to these functions. Avoid long conditional
expressions when testing a character for being a vowel and a consonant. Instead, use two global arrays
(tables) containing Boolean flags to implement vowel() and consonant(). For example, an array named
is_vowel would have true for characters ’a’ and ’A’ but false for ’b’ and ’B’.

```
// function that returns 0 if c is a consonant, or 1 if c is not a consonant
bool consonant(char c)
{
const bool is_conson[30]={0,0,...1,1,1,0,0...};

return is_conson[c];

}

//Here is The Code (C++) that I wrote for testing purpose only using Dev-C++

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

bool consonant(char c)
{
const bool is_conso[30]= {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1};

return is_conso[c];

}


int main()
{
int i;
 bool result;
char c;
char sentence[]="aaaabbbbb";

cout<<"the array: ";
cout<<sentence<<endl;
for (i=0; i<9; i++)
{
    c=sentence[i];

    result=consonant(c);
    if (result==0)

        cout<<c<<"  is a Consonant"<<endl;      
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please put the _actual_ code. Also, why is there 30 elements in an array checking for 26-letter alphabet? Finally, do you realize that you shouldn't directly put `'a'` or `'A'` constants as indices to the array?

Comment: Where did you come up with 30 for the number of elements in `is_conson`? (hint - 30 isn't big enough)

Comment: I just choose 30 for a test purpose, but I will write the correct code whenever I have all the information missing. It was actually 256.

Comment: We need a concrete question about programming, rather than a request for "hints" or "tips" or "guidance".

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call `bool consonant(char c)` like `consonant('a')`, then you need to translate `c` into an index first (because `'a'` != `0`) or use another approach.

In portable C++, you could do it with a big `switch`:

```
switch(c) {
case 'b': case'B': case 'c': case 'C': .... return true;
default: return false;
}
```

In non-portable C++, you could offset `c`:

```
c = lower_case(c); // <-- left as exercise
const auto array_size = std::end(is_conson) - std::begin(is_conson);
if (c>=0 && c<array_size)
    return is_conson[c - 'a']

throw std::logic_error(...);
```

This is non-portable because the C++ standard does not require the characters `[a..z]` to be contiguous. I don't know if your compiler at hands does support this.

A third, non-portable variant requires separate some special initialization, but allows direct indexing:

```
std::array<bool,std::numeric_limits<char>::max()> meh() {
    std::array<bool,std::numeric_limits<char>::max()> ret;
    ret['a'] = true;
    ret['A'] = true;
    ...
    return ret;
}

....

    static const auto is_conson = meh();
    if (c >= begin(is_conson) && c<= end(is_conson))
        return is_conson[c];
    throw std::logic_error(....);
```

Non-portable, because it assumes that all consonants are positive. It is, however, more portable than the previous variant. You could make it portable by also introducing `std::numeric_limits<char>::min()`.

Comment: It strikes me that checking for a vowel and inverting would be a more effective use of time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Interesting thought, but then what's with `!is_vowel('1')`, for an instance?

Comment: Meh. Well... use a troolean!

Answer (score 0):

As it stands your function won't work because ASCII A is 65, you'll need to increase your array to cover all ASCII characters or subtract 'A' (which gives the ASCII value of A) to scale the number to your array. ASCII a is 97, so lowercase letters would have to be scaled by subtracting 'a'

Answer (score 0):

Letters are represented by values 65 through 90 (uppercase) and 97 through 122 (lowercase) in ASCII. You're using the array as if they were starting at index 0. Do something like this:

```
if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
    return is_conson[c-'A'];
if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
    return is_conson[c-'a'];
return false;
```

Also, you should declare the `is_conson` array as `static`, so that it's only constructed once and not each time the function is called.